# Writing multiple dictionaries to multiple csv files in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I have been struggling with this for a while now, maybe someone can help.
I have a list of dictionaries. Each of these dictionaries should be written to a separate .csv file. How do I do this?

What I have so far, which does not work:

```
from openpyxl import *
from openpyxl.styles import *
import csv

a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
e = 5
f = 6
g = 7
h = 8

one = {'A':a,'B':b}
two = {'C':c,'D':d}
three = {'E':e,'F':f}
four = {'G':g,'H':h}
list = [one,two,three,four]

def main():
    for eachfilename, eachdict in enumerate(list):
        with open(eachfilename, 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            for line in eachdict: 
                writer.writerow(line)   

main()
```

In the end I would like to have four .csv files looking like this:

File1:

```
A,a
B,b
```

File2:

```
C,c
D,d
```

File3: ...

Comment: Would be nice if you could explain why your current code doesn't work.

Comment: BTW do you see anything sensible (i.e. a filename and a dictionary which is what your following code seems to assume) if you add a simple `print eachfilename,eachdict` after the first `for` loop in main?

Answer (score 2):

You have several issues with your code that you need to resolve first.

1. Variable names cannot be integers
2. Variables a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h are all undefined.
3. The argument that you pass into `csv.writer()` must have have `write()` functionality - in your case it should be a File object. Hence you should use `csv.writer(csvfile)`, not `csv.writer(eachfilename)`.

Comment: The whole idea of the minimal example is that it _runs_ and in so doing _shows your problem_, allowing readers to understand and reproduce the problem to help you with it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign a dictionary to an integer value. Try this:

```
import csv
s = [{'A':a,'B':b}, {'C':c,'D':d}, {'E':e,'F':f}, {'G':g,'H':h}]
new_data = [["{},{}".format(a, b) for a, b in i.items()] for i in s]
write = csv.writer(open('filename.csv'))
write.writerows(new_data)
```